# PostgreSQL: Storing large volume of photos and attached tags: many-to-many relationship or array of text?

Tags: postgresql, array

This is my first post here and I am quite new to PostgreSQL - many apologies if my question may appear a bit unclear.

We set up a database for storing a large volume of photo-metadata with attached Hashtags/tags (about 500 Million photos and about 1 to two Billion Hashtags, about 50 Million of those distinct/unique).

We just started to experiment and we're unclear which path to follow for storing hashtags. Two possible options we examined:

- Many-to-Many relationship

  - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql): this would mean creating 3 Tables

  > Table: Photos
  >   Columns: Photo_ID, Photo_Title, Content
  >
  > Table: Tags
  >   Columns: Tag_ID, Tag_Title
  >
  > Table: Photo_Tags
  >   Columns: Photo_ID, Tag_ID
- Use an Array-Field and create a GIN index over it, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns), [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADjkO6gpo%3D9bbFjO7Jrm-kNjoZeQ%2BbGnTjz6Y9u6pQ3-p6K8ng%40mail.gmail.com) and [here](http://openmymind.net/Introduction-To-PostgreSQL-Arrays/):

```sql
--adapted from the link above
CREATE TABLE "Photos"("Column1" text[]);
INSERT INTO "Photos" VALUES ('{tree, street, green}');
INSERT INTO "Photos" VALUES ('{tree, house, red}');

CREATE INDEX idx_photos on "Photos" USING GIN ("Column1");

-- To enforce index usage because we have only 2 records for this test... 
SET enable_seqscan TO off;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM "Photos" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[tree];
```

Which one of the two approaches would be faster for our structure/volume?
We will need to query both
- either for for a single hashtag giving a list of (thousands of) photos
- or querying for thousands of photos with their respective tags attached

Thanks a lot for experience/suggestions!

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run, then they are worth

Comment: Many thanks to both of you! The article confirms what I was feeling: arrays are much better for our approach, but my colleagues argued against me.

Comment: What I don't understand, why do I read everywhere then that normalization is better? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column) for example)

Comment: As always, it all depends on the usage pattern. Sometimes arrays make sense, sometimes they don't. E.g. if you would like to ensure that you only store pre-defined tags, then an array wouldn't work as you can't have a proper foreign key. Also arrays aren't efficient if you store thousands or even millions of elements in them (which is not the case for tags).

Comment: Very good, thanks for your explanation! So I conclude I will stick with arrays. I am still contemplating whether it might make sense to replace tags with an array of TagID's in my photo table that refers to a ID->Tag Table just to save space (unanswered discussion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADjkO6gpo%3D9bbFjO7Jrm-kNjoZeQ%2BbGnTjz6Y9u6pQ3-p6K8ng%40mail.gmail.com)). This doesn't change much that arrays are the way to go for me. Thanks a lot!